# How to stop Microsoft Visual Studio from complaining when missing multiple projects from solution file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio and have a problem when opening a solution file. The solution file consists of a core project and multiple plugin projects. During development, there may be instances where every plugin project is not extracted with the core.

When opening this solution file during development, Visual Studio will complain about missing plugin projects and will have a separate pop-up window for each missing project. Is there some setting in Visual Studio to turn off this warning? Ideally, I do not want to have multiple instances of the solution file or create a script to modify the solution file every time a new project is extracted from our repository. I looked through all of the settings and could not find a flag or warning to turn off.

Answer (score 0):

You might have build the project in the previous version (i.e 2008) and trying to open in the newer version (i.e 2010).